# Getting 404s on New Pages

Tags: 404-error

Can't figure out why this would be happening- wp install issue or .htaccess issue?

I am using a theme but the same problem occurs with the default wp themes. After I create a new page (example: about), I get a 404 when I try to access it from the navigation or when I just enter the URL: domain.com/dev/about, I am also getting 404.

WP installed in httpdocs/dev.

All plugins are deactivated. Everything else appears to be working correctly.

Comment: i should add that this is a brand new fresh/clean WP install. no extra custom code, no content.

Comment: Did you save your permalinks with a new structure other than the default(s)? `Settings > Permalinks <save>`

Comment: We just switched it back to  Default and now pages are loading correctly. Any ideas why changing permalinks to Post Names throws 404s?

Comment: do you get your server's 404 page, or a WordPress 404?

Comment: the WordPress 404

Comment: i was mistaken. it is actually the server 404.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is not receiving requests, check if mod_rewrite is enabled and an .htaccess file is being generated by WordPress (assuming you are using Apache, not IIS).

See [using pretty permalinks and fixing permalink problems](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) for more info.

Comment: Still getting the server 404 pages and mod_rewrite is enabled and the .htaccess file is:

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file to: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Comment: ...because under Permalinks settings, above that code snippet it says: "If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file." I am now getting the WP theme 404, not the server 404 like before.